# Using EF to do a simple query is 1s faster than using Nhibernate.Why?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, nhibernate

I thought NHibernate is faster than EF. But this code shows me, EF is around 1s, but Nhibernate is around 2~4s. Anything wrong with the query?

gist link:https://gist.github.com/d271f4ca0276cca7d481

It is a single table, no links, no relation with others, but just 300k rows data.

MySQL.EF5,NHibernate 3.3.

Comment: Small tip: you can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for time measurements.

Comment: In addition to using the Stopwatch class, you need to move ISessionFactory initialization out of the NHibernate test method for this to be a fair test.

Comment: @JamieIde The watch started after the sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession(). These nothing with the session factory initalization in this comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I can see nothing wrong with the query used in the test. The thing with the test is that it measures a bulk processing operation, which outside NHibernate's target use case.

Also, NHibernate does not have performance as the top goal, and it should not be evaluated solely on that parameter. That is to say, if performance is your single most important factor, you might be better of with something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience with NHibernate the problem is, that the ISessionFactory needs the most time to be created. There all mappings are made, cache is initialized and so on.

Also querying with NHibernate works in another way than EF. EF compiles the "Linq"-Expression Tree and builds the SQL Statement based on the used Driver.

In NHibernate you write the query yourself in an own syntax. Compared to EF this is slower.

That's the experience I made. Maybe other folks can give a deeper dive.

Comment: In the test he is using LINQ also for NHibernate. NHibernate will internally convert this to a parsed HQL expression (not an HQL string) and then to SQL. This conversion (or "compile-to-SQL" if you like) is then cached, so much of this query conversion will be skipped if the same query is used again. On the other hand, the time to do the query conversion should be on the order of milliseconds, so this is not why @ValidfroM is seeing higher execution times from NHibernate.